# Using '*' instead of '_' in imports

Tags: scala

I have a project which is the code of an API.
In `build.sbt` the version of Scala is:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
```

In several Scala files I see imports using `*` instead of `_` like this:

```
...
import sttp.tapir.*
...
```

How is that? It is my understanding that `*` can be used in Scala 3, but not in 2.1x ... I can't see any library (it's a big codebase) or something related to this ...
Why does it works instead of showing compiling errors?

Comment: You are correct. `*` is the syntax for wildcard imports in Scala 3 and `_` in Scala 2. Scala 2 does not allow `*` in that position. The code is being compiled with Scala 3 if it works.

Comment: Unless there in an object / class / type / def called `*`? Not sure if that is even possible but seems reasonable.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That's... I'd never thought of that. How *do* you import a class called `*` in Scala 3? Because that's definitely a valid class name.

Comment: Not necessarily, if something is like a keyword or reserved symbol you need to use backticks so both name as well as import could be`\`*\``. And as @Gaël J wrote these are usable with `-Xsource:3`, it has some other things backported to Scala 2.13.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To ease migration to Scala 3, some syntax of Scala 3 can be used in Scala 2.

See for instance the release note of Scala 2.13.7:

> Align with Scala 3
>
> ...
>
> Allow `import x.{*, given}` under `-Xsource:3` (#9724 by @smarter)
>
> ...

(https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.7)

Though I'm not sure since when it is possible to use `import X.*` (in my understanding, this existed before 2.13.7).

Comment: yes, it is related to -Xsource:3. I had to update IntelliJ to fully support this feature. Thanks!